# Integrate appcelerator view into native project

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

We have an appcelerator project, and we would like to export a couple of views from that project into a native project (let's say iOS first, but eventually Android).

Answer (score 1):

With [Titanium Hyperloop](https://github.com/appcelerator/hyperloop-examples/tree/master/src) you can go the other way around, but ATM there's no way to import Titanium views in Xcode storyboards or controllers.